# Sum of time series based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

this is my dataframe

```
date                          cash   name
2020-06-04 06:32:09.244641    248    Player 1
2020-06-04 06:32:09.729418    217    Player 2
2020-06-04 06:32:10.123283    521    Player 3
2020-06-04 06:32:11.002336    527    Player 4
2020-06-04 06:32:18.049471    616    Player 5
...
2020-06-04 06:42:10.244641    258    Player 1
2020-06-04 06:42:10.729418    227    Player 2
2020-06-04 06:42:11.523283    531    Player 3
2020-06-04 06:42:12.002336    529    Player 4
2020-06-04 06:42:17.049471    636    Player 5
```

This is a time series of the amount of cash per player.
How would you get the total amount of cash as a time series?

So in this case it should be something like this:

```
2020-06-04 06:32:09.244641    248 + 217 + 521 + 527 + 616
2020-06-04 06:42:17.049471    258 + 227 + 531 + 529 + 636
```

How do you achieve this?

Comment: What is logic to get the sum here? Over all Players?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, sum of all the players

Comment: What is the logic here to sum ?  by mins?

Comment: So I would like to see the total amount of cash in the game per timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not like the expected output, but your last comment *I would like to see the total amount of cash in the game per timestamp* makes me think that you could be looking for the cumulative amount `cumsum`, taking into account the first amount of the player and then when the same payer is again in the data you just want to count for the difference of them amount with `groupby.diff`.

```
df['total_cash'] = (df.groupby('name')['cash'].diff() #evolution of cash per player
                      .fillna(df['cash']) # add the original value
                      .cumsum()
                   )
print (df)
                        date  cash      name  total_cash
0 2020-06-04 06:32:09.244641   248  Player 1       248.0
1 2020-06-04 06:32:09.729418   217  Player 2       465.0 #here it is 248+217
2 2020-06-04 06:32:10.123283   521  Player 3       986.0
3 2020-06-04 06:32:11.002336   527  Player 4      1513.0
4 2020-06-04 06:32:18.049471   616  Player 5      2129.0 #sum of player 1 to 5
5 2020-06-04 06:42:10.244641   258  Player 1      2139.0 #+10 for palyer 1 so +10 in total
6 2020-06-04 06:42:10.729418   227  Player 2      2149.0
7 2020-06-04 06:42:11.523283   531  Player 3      2159.0
8 2020-06-04 06:42:12.002336   529  Player 4      2161.0
9 2020-06-04 06:42:17.049471   636  Player 5      2181.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is basically groupby the `cumcount` on `name`:

```
(df.groupby(df.groupby('name').cumcount())
   .agg({'date':'min','cash':'sum'})
)
```

Output:

```
                         date  cash
0  2020-06-04 06:32:09.244641  2129
1  2020-06-04 06:42:10.244641  2181
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')).agg({'date':'first','cash':'sum'})
```